# Laravel new method POST in addition to resources

Tags: php, laravel, post, routes, laravel-5

I have a resource :

```
Route::resource('star', 'StarController');
```

I would like to add a new method POST like this :

```
Route::post('star/addPic', array('as' => 'addpic', 'uses' => 'StarController@addPic') );
Route::resource('star', 'StarController');
```

I tried multiple definitions of my method like this :

```
 public function addPic($id)
 {
     return 'test';
 }
```

or

```
 public function addPic(Request $request)
 {
     return 'test';
 }
```

But in anycase, when i make a request POST to star/addPic i got an error :

```
No query results for model [App\Star].
```

I tried with method in GET and that works :

```
Route::get('star/addPic', array('as' => 'addpic', 'uses' => 'StarController@addPic') );
Route::resource('star', 'StarController');
```

but not in POST, that does not work ...

Hope you could help

**EDIT :**

In trying your advice, i think the request works, but I got a new error :

```
TokenMismatchException in compiled.php line 2710:
```

Comment: Does addPic get called at all? The error you're getting is a result of an Eloquent query, and for sure it's not something the posted addPic method does.

Comment: No, addPic isn't call. When i try to make a request with http://requestmaker.com/ for exemple, i got the error HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error ....... When i changed by GET method, that worked and i got the 200 OK response

Comment: Then check your log files to see why you got the error. Or enable debugging in your .env file - the exception details should be then displayed in the browser

Comment: Debug is activated and the error is the one i wrote in the post : "No query results for model [App\Star]."

Comment: And is the order of the routes in your routes.php in the same order as you posted? When you get the error, do you see where it is thrown from?

Comment: No i don't, maybe you will : here is the whole error : https://i.gyazo.com/62b9f80b12ed06688f031051329f9633.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86673/discussion-between-dramixx-and-jedrzej-kurylo).

Comment: I edited my post, maybe that can help

Answer (score 0):

But, you add the id?

```
Route::post('star/addPic/{id}', array('as' => 'addpic', 'uses' => 'StarController@addPic')
```

This will work with

```
public function addPic($id){}
```

Comment: I tried and that does not work. And i don't understand why i should put the {id} in a POST method. I should put {id} if i would a GET method right ?

Comment: Use the id to find what model you want to modify, and you can use public function (Request $request, $id) {}

Comment: ok, so, i set the route post('star/addPic/{id})) , I set the method public function (Request $request, $id) , and then how i call it ? because i do not manage to do it ... I try to call by {!! link_to_route('addpic', 'test button', [$picture], ['class' => 'btn btn-info pull-right']) !!}

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION :**

OK I managed to do it :

I kept my routes like this :

```
Route::post('star/addPic', array('as' => 'addpic', 'uses' => 'StarController@addPic') );
Route::resource('star', 'StarController');
```

Controller looks like this :

```
public function addPic(Request $request, $id)
```

And the call in POST requires a token (that i forgot too) :

```
jQuery.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/laravelProject/star/addPic",
            data: {
                "_token" : jQuery('#token').val(),
                "urlString" : elmt.src            
            }
        });
```

And that works ;)